# Analysis Exception in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe 'people' with the below mentioned structure.

| name | age | gender | legal | location | stateIndex | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rahul | 23 | M | true | Mumbai Maharashtra | 7 | Maharashtra |
| rohan | 21 | M | false | Delhi UT | 6 | UT |
| rutvick | 24 | M | true | Pune Maharashtra | 5 | Maharashtra |
| unnati | 22 | F | false | Bengaluru Karnataka | 10 | Karnataka |
| saloni | 20 | F | false | Chennai TamilNadu | 8 | TamilNadu |

why is this piece of line giving 'Analysis Exception' couldn't understood.

`people2.select(position(" ","location")).show()`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTGPy.png)

It's working fine with the SQL expression `people2.select(expr("position(' ' in location)")).show()` but cannot understand why the above piece keeps throwing error even though the syntax is proper.

Comment: Please do not add a screenshot of the stracktrace, rather copy and paste the entire stack trace